# How can I debug this script so that numbers are substituted to where there is a % in python?

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong?

I am trying to execute a basic code and I can't understand why the print function won't define the values with the '%' syntax. Any suggestions on what I can do to improve would be greatly appreciated. I am using Python 3.

```
people == 30
cars == 40
buses == 15

print ("There are %s cars on the road.") % (cars)
print ("There are %s buses outside the school.") % (buses)
print ("There are %s at the swimming pool today.") % (people)
```

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: Could you show the code please

Comment: Without actual code, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. But I suspect you can find the answer you're looking for at https://pyformat.info.

Comment: String formatting is what you are looking for. If you are on python3, I'd recommend [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Comment: The code you show would be valid syntax in Python 2.x, but invalid syntax in Python 3 and newer (where `print` is a function and not a statement). What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Code uploaded following first post on Stack Flow.

Comment: @DanielPryden It's actually valid syntax in Python 3, but it will be parsed as a function call and a modulo operation... since `print` returns `None` it results in a `TypeError` at runtime... (for the OP, in Python 3 you would have to put `(cars)`, `(buses)` or `(people)` inside the parentheses after the string in order to do the string interpolation correctly).

Comment: Good point @jdehesa, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some problems in your code

- Assigment is done using the `=` operator, not the `==` operator which is used for comparison
- The formatting variable will be inside the print statement and not outside it
- You don't need to surround your variables around `()` to use your variables in formatting

Hence the changed code will be as follows, and note that it will work for both `python2` and `python3`

```
#Use assignment operator
people = 30
cars = 40
buses = 15

#Use variables inside the print statement, which replaces the formatting operator
print("There are %s cars on the road." % cars)
print("There are %s buses outside the school." % buses)
print("There are %s at the swimming pool today." % people)
```

The output will be

```
There are 40 cars on the road.
There are 15 buses outside the school.
There are 30 at the swimming pool today.
```

Starting python3.7 we have a new way of formatting string using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), where the variable name is replaced inside the `{var}`

```
#Use assignment operator
people = 30
cars = 40
buses = 15

#Use variables inside the f-strings
print(f"There are {cars} cars on the road.")
print(f"There are {buses} buses outside the school.")
print(f"There are {people} at the swimming pool today.")
```

We also have [string.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to print statements, compatible for both `python2` and `python3` again, where the variables are replaced inside the `{}` in the string

```
#Use assignment operator
people = 30
cars = 40
buses = 15

#Use format strings
print("There are {} cars on the road.".format(cars))
print("There are {} buses outside the school.".format(cars))
print("There are {} at the swimming pool today.".format(buses))
```

Answer (score 3):

In python 2.7.15 (it could be other versions honestly probably is but I use this version) if you get rid of one of the equal signs it will work. Check it out below

```
people = 30
cars = 40
buses = 15

print("There are %s cars on the road.") % (cars)
print("There are %s buses outside the school.") % (buses)
print("There are %s at the swimming pool today.") % (people)
```

In python 3 and above you can do the following method * notice the minor differences in the print statements. Where you had an extra parentheses in the print statement. Also as per the comment by @Daniel Pryden you don't need the parentheses

```
people = 30
cars = 40
buses = 15

print("There are %s cars on the road." % cars)
print("There are %s buses outside the school." %  buses)
print("There are %s at the swimming pool today."  %  people)
```

Lastly the other method as mentioned in the comments is using the .format function. The .format() function is a method of the string which class allows you to do variable substitutions and value formatting. This lets you concatenate elements together within a string through positional formatting. The definition above is from Digital Ocean the link is [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3)

```
people = 30
cars = 40
buses = 15
print("There are {} cars on the road.".format(cars))
print("There are {} buses outside the school.".format(buses))
print("There are {} at the swimming pool today.".format(people))
```

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned before, the `=` operator is used for [assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). The `==` operator is used for [value comparison expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Regarding printing formatted output, in Python 3.6 or newer, the recommended approach is to use [formatted string literals (aka f-strings)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) instead.

Putting this together, here is a corrected version for Python 3.6 or newer:

```py
people = 10
cars = 40
buses = 15

print(f'There are {cars} cars on the road.')
print(f'There are {buses} buses outside the school.')
print(f'There are {people} at the swimming pool today.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of typo errors I fixed:

```
people = 30
cars = 40
buses =15

print ("There are %s cars on the road."  %  cars)
print ("There are %s buses outside the school." %  buses)
print ("There are %s at the swimming pool today."  %  people)
```